# Generating file with PDFKit on Heroku - No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, pdfkit, cedar

I'm using PDFKit to create pdfs of from a given url within a Resque job on Heroku Cedar. My code looks like:

```
kit = PDFKit.new(url)
pdf = kit.to_file("/tmp/#{SecureRandom.hex}.pdf")
```

I then upload the file using fog to S3 for permanent storage. This job usually works, but also fails maybe a third of the time with:

```
No such file or directory - /tmp/a05c165fc80878b75fd15c447695de71.pdf
```

Manually running through the code in console will produce the same error.

According to the Heroku docs, I should be able to write a temporary file anywhere in the app's directory on Cedar. I've tried creating the tmp directory first (in console) but that didn't seem to change anything. Neither did saving to "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{SecureRandom.hex}.pdf".

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The full error in console is:

```
Error: Failed loading page http://grist.org/living/you-look-great-in-green-clothing-industry-gets-a-makeover-maybe.html
(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/55a1d418074736decfd4e123d8e2bba2.pdf
```

It seems that maybe this is an error coming from wkhtmltopdf, however, I'm not sure where to add this flag if I'm using wkhtmltopdf via PDFkit.

Comment: " then upload the file using fog to S3" this is all done in the same worker process, yes? Otherwise you could be writting to one dyno's tmp and trying to access from another dyno, which wont work.

Comment: Hi. yes, this is done in the same worker process. The second line is actually object.pdf = kit.to_file("/tmp?#{SecureRandom.hex}.pdf"); object.save. Calling save on the object triggers fog to upload the image.

Comment: @middkidd issue is solved?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the solution, as the error I posted second suggested, was to ignore the load error. I did this with:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options[:load_error_handling] = 'ignore'
end
```

I wasn't seeing this warning at first because Resque was only showing me the final error. Thanks @ctshryock, your question made me think a little more about exactly where this error was coming from.