# PDFKit usage Rails 5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

I have managed installing PDFKit and wkhtmltopdf on Windows 10 for using with Rails 5.

But I can't find any relevant exemple on how to render a `html.erb` file to PDF.

I took a look on this : [pdfkit Usage](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#usage) and it works to save any website to PDF.

I have a `<div>` that I want to render to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `Wicked_pdf gem` to generate quick and easy pdfs on rails. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/pdf-generation-rails/) are some examples for both `wicked pdf` and `pdfkit`.

Comment: @maxpuissant I also can help you with some source codes through Wicked_pdf if you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer @ATF, I tried this 
In my controller :  `kit = PDFKit.new(File.new('app/views/daoes/edit.html.erb'))
    kit.to_file(Rails.root + 'demo.pdf')` 

I have the following error in my terminal : 
`Error: Failed loading page file:///mnt/c/Users/Harri/Documents/argia/app/views/daoes/edit.html.erb (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)                                                     Exit with code 1, due to unknown error. `

Comment: @max Take a look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662756/generating-file-with-pdfkit-on-heroku-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: It's better, in terminal I see the full processing through `Printing pages (6/6)`
But the generated PDF is empty.

Comment: @MaxPuissant have you installed this gem ? 
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.3'
it could be a reason . let me know if it worked !

Comment: @MaxPuissant and did you check the mime_types.rb ? I mean add the pdf related mime type too

Comment: No, I don't know what mime types are, can you explain me ?

Comment: @MaxPuissant if you are using rails app you have to register the file types you are handling in your application like pdf - word excel or ... first install the gem I mentioned before and then add this to config/initializers/mime_types.rb :
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
and take a look at this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html

Comment: @MaxPuissant if it didn't help please let me know through my email : 
afsanefadaei@hotmail.com I will help you in another way

Comment: Done, still generating empty PDF's :(

Comment: omg it's working. I put `html = render_to_string(:action => "edit", :layout => false)
    kit = PDFKit.new(html)
    kit.to_file(Rails.root + 'demo.pdf') ` in my controller.

Comment: @MaxPuissant good for you. you can answer your question below and check it as a true answer to help others fix the same issue :)

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

1) Add `gem 'pdfkit`
         `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'` to Gemfile.

2) Run `bundle install`

3) Install wkhtmltopdf, and run `which wkhtmltopdf` then paste this path to `config/initializers/pdfkit.rb`

```
`# config/initializers/pdfkit.rb
     PDFKit.configure do |config|
      config.wkhtmltopdf = '/home/harri/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf'
      config.default_options = {
        :page_size => 'A4',
        :encoding      => 'UTF-8',
        :print_media_type => true
      }
      config.default_options[:load_error_handling] = 'ignore'
```

# Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
  config.root_url = "http://localhost"
  config.verbose = false
end `

4) In your controller :

```
`html = render_to_string(:action => "edit", :layout => false)
      kit = PDFKit.new(html)
      kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css"
      #kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/public/system/daoe/daoe" + @daoe.id.to_s+'.pdf')
send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'`
```

Use kit.to_file if you want to save the PDF, or send_data if you want to render the PDF fullpage.